# Bluetooth macaddress is different address

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new in Bluetooth low energy for scanning bluetooth device using UUID , the problem is successfully scanning bluetooth device but bluetooth mac address is not device mac address, its randomly generated mac address.

I am tried with `BLE` using  `uuid` to scan callback it is working fine , but the problem is the device `bluetooth` mac address is not correct, but name of the device is correct.

```
ScanFilter scanFilter = new ScanFilter.Builder()
                            .setServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(SERVICE_UUID))
                            .build();
            List<ScanFilter> scanFilters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
            scanFilters.add(scanFilter);
            ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder().build();
            mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(scanFilters, scanSettings, scanCallback);
```

I need the correct `bluetooth` mac address for scanning device, but showing wrong address.

Comment: check this http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/4-0/tutorial/tutScanAndPairAPI/ it may help you.

Comment: First, Bluetooth doesn't have MAC addresses. It has Bluetooth Device Addresses. Are you meaning you get a random resolvable address while you are expecting a static random or public one?

Comment: Here is the answer: https://microchipdeveloper.com/wireless:ble-link-layer-address

Comment: the device can set it's bluetooth address in runtime randomly

Answer (score -1):

This is a privacy feature of Bluetooh LE. The Blog of the [Bluetooth SIG] has a nice post about it and how to deal with it:
https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/bluetooth-technology-protecting-your-privacy/

Comment: link-only answers are always bad answers, as they don't contain an answer itself, and the link could become invalid any moment